# Cannot create new PageRequest (has protected access error)

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I am coding a Spring Boot system which connects to the database. While implementing functions that change the state of the entity, I faced the following problem:

```
'PageRequest(int, int, org.springframework.data.domain.Sort)' has protected access in 'org.springframework.data.domain.PageRequest'
```

in this:

```
@Override
public List<Picture> getAllPictures(int pageNumber, int pageSize) {
    return pictureRepository.findAll(new PageRequest(pageNumber, pageSize)).getContent();
}
```

How can I solve it? Is it something else that is similar to `PageRequest` and could replace it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[This](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/commons/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/domain/PageRequest.html) piece of documentation will help you definitely..Look at the `PageRequest.of()`